# C# - YAML to JObject

Tags: c#, json, yaml

I have a C# project with a bunch of JSON, and subsequent use of Newtonsoft JObject, but I'd really, really like to be using YAML instead (although I don't expect to be able to use YAML references).

Are there any C# libraries to turn YAML into a JObject, or something equivalent?

If there aren't, does anyone know a regexp that can be run in C# to convert YAML to JSON?

And if *that* still fails, how would I call to the command line to, say, have a Ruby/Perl/Python one-liner to convert the YAML to JSON to then feed into a JSON deserializer? Or other crazy multilingual solutions, since I suspect there might be a way to wedge some C/C++ in there?

Thanks!

PS - Needs to work with Mono 2.6 / .NET 3.5 aka Unity3D 4.5

PPS - I've gone hunting. I can't tell if YAML.NET is an *editor* or a *deserializer*.

Comment: Get you started: https://yamlserializer.codeplex.com/. NET 3.5 compatible

Comment: Actually, that looks like it. And if it is, I actually have different questions...

Comment: So, almost does everything I would have wanted it to do... except it can't deserialize Unity components. Regardless, this looks like exactly what I was after in this question, if not in my actual real-world use case.